# Why is postgresql 9.1 not working with rails 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu-11.04

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 11.10 and whenever I run my rails server I keep getting this error:

```
  could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Prior to the upgrade the database was working fine with rails 3.0. How can I fix this?

Comment: The question might be better suited on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Fixed it. The problem was that postgresql was listening on 5433 instead of 5432. Just changed the port in the database.yml file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it. The problem was that postgresql was listening on 5433 instead of 5432. Just changed the port in the database.yml file.

Answer (score 3):

This is the standard error message, when the server cannot be found. Mostly this simply means that you **haven't started the server** (with your database cluster at the standard port 5432).

On Ubuntu with postgres 9.1, if you installed correctly, you would:

```
pg_ctl start
```

You will have to be user `root` or `postgres` for that. Or the general way to do it:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.1 start
```

If Ubuntu installs the Debian wrapper by Martin Pitt (that's standard in Debian, not sure about Ubuntu):

```
pg_ctlcluster 9.1 main start
```

#### More info

- [Ubuntu help site for PostgreSQL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL)
- [Ubuntu manual on PostgreSQL](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/pg_ctl.1.html)
- PostgreSQL manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-createdb.html) or [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/server-start.html)
- Or, of course: `man pg_ctl`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some linux distributions supply a postgresql server with the unix domain socket in a different place than usual ( /tmp ). For psql you can supply the path_to_the_socket via the -h parameter, e.g:

```
psql -h /tmp/ mydatabasename
```

(you could use this to test if it actually works)
Maybe ruby has a way to supply the same setting in one of its connector settings.

Comment: The path `/var/run...` in the question indicates, that the client already tries a non-standard path.